# I am having problems programming java on aide app

Tags: java

The app is supposed to call one screen from another and use the other screen's layout components. Whenever I try to call a component, such as `ImageButton`, it says that member id is unknown, I told my teacher and he says that it shouldn't happen. I have tried renaming the components and even made a new project.

How can I fix it?
the error is in R.id

```
package com.movil.ejemploventanas;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class DatosPersonales extends Activity {
EditText vEdtNom,vEdtEdad;
ImageButton vBtnOrigen,vBtnSantuario;
Intent intnEnvio;
Bundle bndContenedorEnvio;
String strNom;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.datospersonales);
    vEdtNom=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtNom);
    vEdtEdad=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtEdad);
    vBtnOrigen=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnOrigen);
    vBtnSantuario=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnSantuario);
    intnEnvio=new Intent(DatosPersonales.this,Caracteristicas.class);
    bndContenedorEnvio=new Bundle();
    vBtnOrigen.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0){
                strNom=vEdtNom.getText().toString();
                bndContenedorEnvio.putString("nom",strNom);
                bndContenedorEnvio.putString("edad", vEdtEdad.getText().toString());
                bndContenedorEnvio.putString("opc","1");
                intnEnvio.putExtras(bndContenedorEnvio);
                startActivity(intnEnvio);
            }
        });
    vBtnSantuario.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0){
                strNom=vEdtNom.getText().toString();
                bndContenedorEnvio.putString("nom",strNom);
                bndContenedorEnvio.putString("edad",vEdtEdad.getText().toString());
                bndContenedorEnvio.putString("opc","2");
                intnEnvio.putExtras(bndContenedorEnvio);
                startActivity(intnEnvio);
            }
        });
}
```

}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:id="@+id/txtLetrero"
    style="style/titulo"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/letMariposa"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/txtLetrero"
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="66dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtNom"
        style="style/letreros"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="string/nom"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtNom"
        style="style/datos"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtEdad"
        style="style/letreros"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/edad"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtEdad"
        style="style/datos"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"/>

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/origen"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    style="style/letreros"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView4"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
    android:id="@+id/btnOrigen"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/sant"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnOrigen"
    android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    style="style/letreros"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnSantuario"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You should include a sample code block in your question. Please avoid using image links as some of us will not be able to access them.

Comment: [Don't post images of code.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: thanks for the observation i just added the codes